# arduino usb android controller

Tags: android, usb

i am pretty much newbie with arduino and want to start my first project so i may be asking stupid questions.

My goal is to make usb controller for android tv (running on raspberry pi or s905). I want it rotary, so turning will be "arrow up/down" or "left/right" (i dont know exact android tv menu controlling) and "return" on push. I found [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-10X-12mm-Rotary-Encoder-Push-Button-Switch-Keyswitch-Electronic-Components-New-/291289671106?var=&hash=item43d237a5c2:m:mFWqvrBn9_vgy9o4j9ucZeg) rotary switch on ebay, is it suitable?

To communicate i want to use arduino. I found libraries [MouseKeyboard](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard), which might be suitable for my needs, will arduino nano support this library or do i need arduino uno?

Do i need something else, or just connect switch to pins on arduino and plug arduino to raspberry?

As i need this controller to operate in menu, not just in some application, will this work as some mouse or keyboard connected via otg to android and function immediately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that rotary encoder is fine.

Neither the Nano nor the Uno support that library. You will need a device that has native USB support such as the Leonardo or Due, just like it says on the page.

The rotary encoder library you use will tell you how to connect it.

As for specific Android functionality, you will need to ask on [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/).